# Understanding Incident/Exitant Radiance

Tags: visible-light, radiometry

Reading "Physically Based Rendering", I'm trying to understand what the meaning  of the incident and exitant radiance functions.

I understand that radiance  $L(p,\omega) =\frac{d^2\phi}{d\omega dA^{\perp}}$ where $\phi$ is the Flux, $\omega$ is the direction of the light coming towards the surface and $A^{\perp}$ is the surface perpendicular to $\omega$ . So, what I'm effectively trying to measure is the "brightness" of the light at this direction $\omega$ . This is where the incident and exitant radiance come in: 
$L_{i}(p,w)$ is described as the radiance arriving at the point p and $L_{o}(p,w)$ as the outgoing reflected radiance from the surface.

I don't understand this concept at all. Isn't $L_{i}(p,w)$ what $L(p,w)$ is in the first place?  Is it the case that $L(p,w) = L_{i}(p,w) + L_{o}(p,w) $ since the "brightness" of a ray can be described as the radiance from all the lightsources in that direction + the radiance from emitted from the surface in that direction as well? Can  someone please explain this concept more intuitively, as I'm trying to understand it for Computer Graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L_i(p,\omega)$ and $L_o(p,\omega)$ are specific kinds of radiance, it is meaningless to compare them to $L(p,\omega)$.

In a vacuum, provided that the $\omega$ vectors point outward from the surface, it is the case that $$L_i(p \leftarrow \omega) = L_o(p \rightarrow -\omega).$$

For more details, read Section 2.2.3 of [Wojciech Jarosz's thesis](https://cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/dissertation/chapter2.pdf).

Moreover, the reflection equation holds: $$L_o(p,\omega_o) = L_e(p,\omega_o) + \int_{H^2} f_r(p, \omega_i \to \omega_o) L_i(p,\omega_i) \cos(\theta_i) d \omega_i,$$ where $H^2$ is the hemisphere, $f_r$ is the BRDF, and $L_e$ is the emitted radiance. This relation relates the outgoing radiance at a point to the incoming radiance, BRDF of the surface, and emitted radiance.